# How to convert multi-line module/class into single line with double colons(::) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is an example of a class I have:

```rb
module Project
  module Alert
    class NotifyService
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to replace that with colons(::).

Option 1:

```rb
module Project::Alert::NotifyService
end
```

Option 2:

```rb
class Project::Alert::NotifyService
end
```

I don't want these to happen:

```rb
# NotWanted A
class Project
  class Alert
    class NotifyService
    end
  end
end

# or
# NotWanted B

module Project
  module Alert
    module NotifyService
    end
  end
end
```

Which is the equivalent of the original one? And is there a way to tell that?

Comment: Option 2, because you still want to create a class.

Comment: So Ruby will automatically recognize the last one as class and others as a module? Because I don't want this to happen: `class Project  class Alert class NotifyService end end end`

Comment: Notice that one-liner definition has different constant finding scope than original.

Comment: @SandipSubedi `class Project::Alert::NotifyService ; end` only creates **one** new class, not three. It assigns that class to the constant `NotifyService` under `Project::Alert`. It expects both constants `Project` and `Project::Alert` to be defined and to be either a class or a module. If they are undefined, you get a `NameError`. If they are neither class nor module, you get a `TypeError`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much for explaining @Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second one, but only if the parent modules actually exist before you start:

**your original:**

```
jonathan@ADAMS-3DJ5PW2:~$ irb
2.5.8 :001 > module Project
2.5.8 :002?>     module Alert
2.5.8 :003?>         class NotifyService
2.5.8 :004?>           end
2.5.8 :005?>       end
2.5.8 :006?>   end
 => nil 
2.5.8 :007 > Project.new
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):7
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Project:Module)
2.5.8 :008 > Project::Alert.new
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):8
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Project::Alert:Module)
2.5.8 :009 > Project::Alert::NotifyService.new
 => #<Project::Alert::NotifyService:0x000055a483abd808> 
2.5.8 :010 > exit
```

**your second (without definition):**

```
jonathan@ADAMS-3DJ5PW2:~$ irb
2.5.8 :001 > class Project::Alert::NotifyService
2.5.8 :002?>   end
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant Project)
Did you mean?  Object
2.5.8 :003 > exit
```

**your second, with the addition of module definitions first:**

```
jonathan@ADAMS-3DJ5PW2:~$ irb
2.5.8 :001 > module Project
2.5.8 :002?>   module Alert
2.5.8 :003?>     end
2.5.8 :004?>   end
 => nil 
2.5.8 :005 > class Project::Alert::NotifyService
2.5.8 :006?>   end
 => nil 
2.5.8 :007 > Project.new
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):7
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Project:Module)
2.5.8 :008 > Project::Alert.new
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/jonathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):8
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Project::Alert:Module)
2.5.8 :009 > Project::Alert::NotifyService.new
 => #<Project::Alert::NotifyService:0x00005604a90e79b0> 
2.5.8 :010 > exit
```

Comment: I understood how it works now. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary `A::B::C` you'd declare it as either:

```rb
module A
  module B
    class C
    end
  end
end
```

Or:

```rb
module A::B # (Presumes module or class A already exists)
  class C
  end
end
```

Or:

```rb
class A::B::C # (Presumes module or class A::B already exists)
end
```

Where in all cases it's of the form `class (NAMESPACE::)NAME` where *NAMESPACE* is optional and *NAME* is the name of your class.